# Kattis 'Digits' question: Why does my first set of code exceed time limit, but my second set does not?

Tags: python

I am currently doing a problem on Kattis (https://open.kattis.com/problems/digits).

The task description is as follows:

Given any number x0, define a sequence using the following recurrence xi+1=the number of digits in the decimal representation of xi
Your task is to determine the smallest positive i such that xi=xi−1.

I came up with code A initially, but after code A failed to meet the time limit, I tinkered around with the code slightly to reach code B.

Sample input

```
42
5
END
```

Sample output

```
3
2
```

Code A:

```
#time limit exceeded
def recurrence_index(prev):
    counter = 1
    while True:
        current = len(str(prev))
        if current == prev:
            return counter
        else:
            counter += 1
            prev = current
    

while True:
    initial = input().strip()
    if initial == 'END':
        break
    initial = int(initial)
    print(recurrence_index(initial))
```

Code B:

```
def recurrence_index(prev):
    counter = 2
    while True:
        current = len(str(prev))
        if current == prev:
            return counter
        else:
            counter += 1
            prev = current
    

while True:
    initial = input().strip()
    if initial == 'END':
        break
    l = len(initial)
    if l == 1 and int(initial) == 1:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(recurrence_index(l))
```

Unfortunately, I am not quite sure why Code B is faster than Code A. It seems that I have arrived at the right answer by luck. If anyone can help explain why code B is faster than code A, your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "It seems that I have arrived at the right answer by luck.* - Nah, rather seems like you identified exactly what the problem was and fixed it.

Comment: @KellyBundy hmm I am not really sure why though I was basically messing around the parameters in an attempt to make the code faster; code B only differs from code A in that  code B will solve for an initial input of 1 faster than code A. However, I was thinking that the time saved would be rather insignificant, as one of the test cases had a googol digits.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, `int(initial)` is expensive on huge huge integers, and that effort is thrown away because you eventually just call str() on it, which could also be expensive.

In the second code, you just directly call `len(initial)`, so you are only ever calling `str()` on small-ish integers less than 1 million, to get lengths less than `len("1000000")==7`.